# What do 'L2' or 'L3' marking codes on electrolytic capacitors mean?

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor, markings

I see a lot of these mysterious marking codes on very old (e.g. 1980) capacitors by different manufacturers.

[image: frako capacitor]

[image: roe capacitor]

Comment: Wild guess: production line number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably (German industry?) standardized case size codes.

[Kemet](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_A4061_ETA.pdf) lists these sizes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, probably you are right.